# Outlook Add Items quits working - Items_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

I am watching for new items and then calling a subroutine.  In place of the subroutine, I am currently using a message box for testing.

Initially the code worked properly.  After running it a few times, it quit working.  If I shut down Outlook and reopened it would work again a few more times.  I searched many sites for answers.

I tried backing up the project file, deleting it, restoring it.   I was able to use this code again for awhile.  Now I can't get it to work, regardless of what I do.  I have been working on this for two days, but I cannot understand what is going wrong.  I'm running Outlook 2010  and my code is posted below.

The code is saved in `This Outlook Session:`

```vb
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items
Private Sub Application_Startup()
  Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
  Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
  Set olApp = Outlook.Application
  Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
  ' default local Inbox
  Set Items = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Access Data Collection Replies").Items
End Sub


Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object)

  On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
  Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem
  If TypeName(item) = "MailItem" Then
    Set Msg = item
    ' ******************
    ' This is going to be the code to respond to the dealer and to call   procedures. Maybe it can be handled with case statements.  Then each event can be identified.
    ' ******************
    MsgBox("It Worked!")
    Call AnswerD

  End If
ProgramExit:
  Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
  MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
  Resume ProgramExit
End Sub
```

Comment: i added complete code on my answer, let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks Aaron D and Omar for your help.

Comment: Thanks @Aaron D and for your help. My problem has been resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code works find, if you are trying to get the msg box to pop then

Move this line code

```
MsgBox ("It Worked!")
```

next to

```
  If TypeName(item) = "MailItem" Then
      MsgBox ("It Worked!")
```

here is complete code tested on  <kbd>**Outlook 2010**</kbd>

```
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim olNameSpace     As Outlook.NameSpace

    Set olNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    '// ' Default local Inbox (olFolderInbox) & sub ("Folder Name")
    Set Items = olNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Access Data Collection Replies").Items
End Sub

Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object)
    If TypeOf item Is Outlook.MailItem Then
        MsgBox ("It Worked!")
        'AnswerD '<-- un-comment to call subroutine.
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub SaveMovePrint(OlMail As Outlook.MailItem)
    'On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    ' ******************
    ' Here subroutine
    ' ******************
ProgramExit:
  Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
  MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
  Resume ProgramExit
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Omar.  Upon further inspection I found that I needed to reorder 2 lines of code in my subroutine "AnswerD."  It was saving the wrong file and I didn't realize that was happening.

Comment: Good to hear you figured